# Get intranet authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, intranet

I am building a web application for my school's intranet. Whenever teachers try to access the browser to access the intranet page a popup appears so they can login, in my page I need to get the logged username. do any of you guys know how to do that?

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

The code above is what I've managed to do so far which gets the username of the user loggin in on windows but that's not really what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use simply the following statement :

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```